# issue with jquery popup responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a login popup. 
I'm starting with jquery and I've looked quite manuals, and not just got the way to make my popup becomes responsive. Here I leave the code popup to see if you can lend a hand as I have one week looking, tasting and ... nothing :(

```js
//scriptLogin.js archive

$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.login-window').click(function() {
    
    //cojemos los valores de las variables desde el link
    var loginBox = $(this).attr('href');

    //creamos el popup
    $(loginBox).fadeIn(300);
    
    //establecemos el padding + border (css)
    var popMargTop = ($(loginBox).height() + 24) / 2; 
    var popMargLeft = ($(loginBox).width() + 24) / 2; 
    
    $(loginBox).css({ 
        'margin-top' : -popMargTop,
        'margin-left' : -popMargLeft
    });
    
    //añadimos la capa mask al body(para hacer fondo semi negro al abrirse el popup)
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
    
    return false;
});

//cuando clikemos el icono X se cerrara el popup
$('a.close, #mask').live('click', function() { 
  $('#mask , .login-popup').fadeOut(300 , function() {
    $('#mask').remove();  
}); 
return false;
});
});
```

```css
/*LOGIN*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .login-popup{
     width:100%;
  }
}

#login-box{
 width:600px;
 height:auto;
}

.login-popup{
 display:none;
 background:#2c3338;
 padding:10px;
 border:2px solid #000;
 float:left;
 font-size:1.2em;
 position:fixed;
 top:40%;
 left:50%;
 z-index:99999;
 color:#606468;
 font-family:'Calibri';
 line-height:1.5em;
}

#signin{
 width:auto;
 height:auto;
 margin:3% 0 0 25%;
}

#fondoLogin{
 background-color:#2c3338;
 color:#606468;
 font-family:'Calibri';
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:1.5em;
}

#signin span{
 background-color:#363b41;
 border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px;
 -moz-border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px 0px 0px 3px;
 color:#606468;
 display:block;
 float:left;
 height:50px;
 line-height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 width:50px;
}

#signin input{
 height:50px;
}

#signin input{
 background-color:#3b4148;
 border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px;
 -moz-border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px;
 -webkit-border-radius:0px 3px 3px 0px;
 color:#606468;
 margin:0 0 2% 5%;
 padding:0 16px;
 width:198px;
}

#signin input:focus{
 border:2px solid #785da1;
 outline:none;
    box-shadow:0 0 10px #785da1;
}

#signin input[type="submit"]{
 width:280px;
 height:55px;
 border-radius:3px;
 -moz-border-radius:3px;
 -webkit-border-radius:3px;
 background-color:#624291;
 color:#eee;
 font-weight:bold;
 margin:2% 0 2% 2%;
}

#signin input[type="submit"]:hover{
 background-color:#7842A6;
}

#signin a{
 color:#eee;
 text-decoration:none;
}

#signin a:hover{
 text-decoration:underline;
}

#signin p{
 width:300px;
 height:auto;
}

#signin input{
 border:none;
 font-family:'Calibri';
 font-size:14px;
 line-height:1.5em;
 padding:0;
 -webkit-appearance:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" lang="es-es">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>
  <link href="css/css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/icSquared_v1.0.css"/>
  <title>...</title>
 </head>
<body>
<div>
 <header>
        <nav role="navigation" class="noround navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
     <span class="sr-only"> Barra de navegación</span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
   </div>
     
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left" style="margin:10px 0 10px 0">
                    <a href="index.php"><img src="fotos/logoH.png" /></a>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="registro.php"> Registrate <span class="fa fa-user-plus" style="font-size:16px; margin-top:5px"></span></a></li>
                    <li><a href="#login-box" class="login-window"> Identificate <span class="fa fa-user" style="font-size:16px; margin-top:5px"></span><span class="caret"></span></a></li>
                        <div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
                            <a href="" class="close"><img src="fotos/x.png" style="width:30px; height:30px" class="btn_close" title="Cerrar Ventana" /></a>
       <form action="action.php?accion=login" method="post" class="form" id="signin">
        
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <p style="margin-left:4%"><span class="fa fa-user"></span>
                                    <input type="text" placeholder="ejemplo@ejemplo.com" name="emailLog" required class="form-control" style="padding-left:16px;" /></p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <p style="margin-left:4%"><span class="fa fa-lock"></span>
                                    <input type="password" placeholder="contraseña" name="passwd" required class="form-control" style="padding-left:16px;" /></p>
                                 </div>
                                 <div class="form-group">
                                    <p><a href="">Has olvidado la contraseña?</a></p>
                                    <p style="height:70px;"><input type="submit" class="btn" id="enviar" value="ENTRAR" /></p>
                                 </div>
                            </form>
                            <p style="margin:2% 0 0 25%">No eres miembro?<a href=""> Registrate Ahora </a><span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
   </div>
        </nav>
 </header>
  
    [...more code that isn't important..]
  
</div>
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scriptLogin.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What if you set `#login-box{ width:600px;` to `#login-box{max-width:600px`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are using bootstrap , Bootstrap also give responsive pop , Look here

```
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/
```

if you want our custom code for responsive pop , Look here , I have write simple code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
.pop_div{ display:none;}
.overrelay{ display:none;}
.pop_div {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 38%;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(247, 247, 95, 0.42);
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    z-index: 12;

}
.close_pop {
    float: right;
    background: #f00;
    padding: 7px;
    border: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    line-height: 9px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}
.overrelay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 10;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
     <div class="responsive_pop">Click me for Responsive POP </div>
     <!---------/// POP HERE ------->
      <div class="pop_div">
           <div class="close_pop">X</div>
         <form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>

      </div>
      <div class="overrelay"></div>
     <!--------/// POP HERE --------->

</body>
  <script>
     $('.responsive_pop').click(function(){

           $('.pop_div').show(500);
           $('.overrelay').show(500);



         });

         $('.close_pop').click(function(){

              $('.pop_div').hide(500);
           $('.overrelay').hide(500);

             });
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow!!! Thanks!! This is a great idea!! Thanks so much, i will take a look at the bootstrap popup too, thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 .login-popup{
     width:100%;
     left: 0;
  }
}

and put it bottom of css file
```

Comment: And please make sure you put <meta name="viewport"> tag in head